# Proof that $a|b \iff ac|bc$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I have to prove, using the concept of divisibility (and no division), that if $c\ne 0$ then $a\mid b \leftrightarrow ac\mid bc$. I first proved $a \mid b \to ac\mid bc$, then got stuck on the opposite process. Here's what I did on the first part (please assume all numbers to be integers):
$$a\mid b$$
$$b=ka$$
$$bc=kac$$
$$ac\mid bc$$
Is this right? 
As for $ac\mid bc \implies a\mid b$, I can't figure out a way to remove $c$ from $b$ without messing everything on $a$'s side.

Googling for an answer, I only found solutions that used division itself, which was of no help. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @Dzoooks for the first half... yes... the OP is having difficulties in performing the second half.  Read the question more carefully.

Comment: Are you sure you understood correctly that you should use "no division"?

Comment: Can you use that if a product is zero, then one of the factors is zero?

Comment: @Phira division is frowned upon for questions at this level pertaining to divisibility properties.

Comment: @Phira yes, the professor made it clear since day 1 of the course that we shouldn't use division.

Comment: @JMoravitz This does not make much sense because use of division in this context is really just the non-existence of zero divisors.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I'm sorry, I don't get your point. Wouldn't that be proof for only a particular case?

Comment: @Phira I assume that the distinction here is to avoid the operation of division, not the properties of division.

Comment: I really think you need to clarify not doing division means and what the justfication for it is.  Clearly as all non zero elements have multiplicative inverses (field definitions) and multiplication is a closed well-defined binary operation, then $a=b \iff ac=bc$ is basic and simple to prove proposition one can and should introduce in the very first day.  And in light of that the "you can not use division" decree seems as arbitrary and as pointless as a "you can not use the letter 'g' decree".  I, for one, would *not* be willing to just "go with it".  It makes no sense as stated.

Comment: @fleablood It appears that the OP is at the level of "introduction to proof"  In that setting, there are pedagogical reasons why one might avoid division.  The first is that one wants to get the students to think about the properties of a definition, i.e., a quantified statement, and not a definition in terms of an algorithm.  For example, many students mistakenly think that $a|b$ is the same as $(b/a)$ is an integer.  Second, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not closed under division, it may take away from the underlying ideas of the proof to include a digression on whether a quantity is an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this is a bit of a cheat (it's barely avoiding division), you could do the following:

Sketch:

Suppose that $ac\mid bc$.  Then there is some integer $k$ so that $ack=bc$.  Therefore, by factoring $c(ak-b)=0$.  Since $c\not=0$, you can conclude something about the other factor...

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 5):

Let $ ac | bc $. Then there is some $ k \in \mathbb{Z} $ such that $ ack = bc $. Then $ (ak - b)c = 0 $. As $ c \neq 0 $ by assumption, we have $ ak - b = 0 $, so $ ak = b $, so $ a | b $.

The property of $ \mathbb Z $ that $ ab = 0 $ implies $ a = 0 $ or $ b = 0 $ is essential to this result, so hopefully using this is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You want to go through your equivalences backwards and of course, you need to divide by $c$. So, the actual question is: How to write the division without calling it division?

$bc=kac \Leftrightarrow c(b-ka)=0$, so since $c$ is not zero you get $b=ka$.

Comment: "So, the actual question is: How to write the division without calling it division?"  I honestly think another legitimate question is why the heck can't we do division?

Comment: @fleablood hahah yes, very much so :)

Answer (score 2):

***Strong Hint:***$$\begin{align}ac&=bc\\ \Leftrightarrow\quad \bigg(\frac 1c\bigg)ac&= \bigg(\frac 1c\bigg)bc \\ \Leftrightarrow\space\, \bigg(\frac 1c\cdot c\bigg)a&= \bigg(\frac 1c\cdot c\bigg)b \\ \Leftrightarrow\quad\quad\:\, 1\cdot a&=1\cdot b \\ \Leftrightarrow\quad\quad\quad\,\,\, a&=b\end{align}$$ This is known as the $\color{green}{\text{Multiplicative Cancellation Law}}$.

Comment: This would apparently not be and acceptable answer as multiplying be the multiplicative inverse is the equivalent (often the very definition) of division and, for inexplicable, unfathomable and unexplained reasons, division is not allowed.  Which isn't to say, your answer isn't the correct one (it clearly is) but that it will not be acceptable by the OP's bizarre and weird class for bizarre and weird reasons.  I really do wish it would be explained why division is not being acceptable.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. This answer is directly from *Modern Mathematics* by J. B. Fitzpatrik and L. Watson. Also, the OP can just change the equals sign to the divisibility sign and what follows is desired. That was what my hint was trying to imply.

Comment: My point is the OP said "and no division" and "solutions that used division itself, which was of no help" and "yes, the professor made it clear since day 1 of the course that we shouldn't use division".  My point is 1) given that division is not allowed this proof won't satisfy to OP and 2) Why the #### does the OP think division is not allowed?  That make absolutely *NO* sense at all!.... in any event, *I* think your answer is perfect and I'm sur Fitzpatrik and Watson don't worry about "You can not use division".  But the OP and professor will not like it.

Comment: @fleablood ok, *now* I understand your point $-$ and yes I very much agree. But I can't blame the OP if his/her professor asked for no division, even though the professor's requirements does not make much sense.